# Is there a runWithValidation feature for Gradient Boosted Trees (GBT) in Spark ml?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning

Wondering if there a runWithValidation feature for Gradient Boosted Trees (GBT) in Spark ml to prevent overfitting. It's there in mllib which works with RDDs. I am looking the same for dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

Found a K-Fold Cross Validation support in Spark. It can be done using CrossValidation() with Estimators, Evaluators, ParamMap and number of folds. This helps in finding the best parameters for the model i.e model tuning.

Refer http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-tuning.html for more details.